# Pass all results from a foreach loop to a new variable

Tags: php, foreach

I have used the following little bit of code to find all links on a page (home.php) and echoed them as URLs. It works fine, but how do I pass the results to a new variable? If I create a new variable:

```
$myvariable ="$element->href";
```

This only echos the last result of many.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.somewebsite.xxx/include/home.php');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Works.

Comment: I have. Ideally I should have marked all 3 as answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate with a [**String Operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$myvar = '';
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       $myvar .= $element->href . '<br>';
}
```

Or use an [**Array**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       $myvar[] = $element->href; // removed <br> for implode, you can add it back
}
// if you want the array as one string
$myvar = implode('<br>', $myvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.somewebsite.xxx/include/home.php');

$urls = array();

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $urls[] = $element->href;
}

print_r($urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Array to hold the values of all the Links from that Page in Question. In the End, the Array is the Variable you are looking for. Here's how:

```
    <?php
        //USE THE HTML DOM PARSER TO PARSE ALL THE HTML DATA ON THE PAGE: $page
        $page   = 'http://www.somewebsite.xxx/include/home.php';
        $html   = file_get_html($page);


        // LOOPING THROUGH THE DOM ELEMENTS SELECT ONLY THE <a> TAGS 
        // AND BUNDLE THEM INTO AN ARRAY...
        // THE ARRAY NOW FORMS THE VARIABLE YOU HAD EXPECTED TO CREATE..
        $arrAnchors     = array();  // INITIALIZE $arrAnchors TO AN EMPTY ARRAY...
        foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
            // PUSH ALL THE ANCHOR'S HREF ATTRIBUTES (URLs) INTO THE $arrAnchors ARRAY
            $arrAnchors[]   = $element->href . '<br>';
        }

        // NOW TRY TO DUMP THE CONTENT OF YOUR $arrAnchors....
        var_dump($arrAnchors);  // DISPLAYS A NUMERICALLY INDEXED ARRAY OF LINKS ON THE PAGE: $page
```